# C# Get generic non-array type from generic array type

Tags: c#, generic-type-argument

Given the following function;

```
void SomeFunction<T>(...){
    SomeOtherFunction<T>();
}
```

This works fine, but sometimes the function fails before T passed is an array type, but it mustn't be an array type. These functions have to do with JSON deserialization of a dictionary, but for some reason it doesn't accept the T array argument when the dictionary has only one entry.

In short, I want to do this

```
void SomeFunction<T>(...){
    try {
    SomeOtherFunction<T>();
    } catch ( Exception e ){
        SomeOtherFunction<T arrayless>();
    }
}
```

I've tried a ton of stuff, and I realize the real problem is somewhere else, but I need to temporary fix this so I can work on a real solution in the deserializer. I tried reflection too using the following method;

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(JToken).GetMethod("ToObject", System.Type.EmptyTypes);
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T).GetElementType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
object result = generic.Invoke(valueToken, null);
```

But that doesn't quite work either.

Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to build exception-based execution flow. This is the direct way to hell.

Comment: Like I said, the problem lies somewhere else and I need a quick fix to get it to work, if it even works. The real fix can take a lot longer and that time isn't available right now.

Comment: @Wotuu: While I certainly can understand that argumentation and I understand that whatever we say here won't change your mind, I still have to say it: These dirty, quick fixes will lead you and your project in a direction where it will become unmaintainable fast. Fix bugs at the root, don't just treat the symptoms. You will have a system with layers of quick fixes overlapping each other, making it a mess.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of this. The problem lies that I already spent a day and a half trying to fix the problem at the root, but there is no ETA of that yet. By checking if this patch works I can continue work on my actual solution while this is in place.

Comment: And it's good that you guys say this, don't get me wrong! But I never do this kind of fixes (trust me!), I just need to have it work now.

Comment: @Wotuu: If you are well aware of the implications and carefully consider the consequences this is a good start.

Comment: My 'solution' didn't work, and it wouldn't have worked as the return types wouldn't have matched. So, it's all good, back to work on the actual solution .. it'll just have to take a bit longer then.

Comment: Rest assured I fixed the actual problem now! Turned out to be I was passing the wrong T type altogether. I have 500 unit tests that look the same and use the same one function, a mistake like that was easily made. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, but to get the type of the elements in an array, you have to use `Type.GetElementType()`:

```
void SomeFunction<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if(type.IsArray)
    {
        var elementType = type.GetElementType();
        var method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("SomeOtherFunction")
                                .MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
        // invoke method
    }
    else
        foo.SomeOtherFunction<T>(...);
}
```

Comment: I editted your answer a bit, and it seems to do what I wanted to do, but it wasn't the quick fix I was hoping for. Either way, this worked, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you want to call one of two generic functions depending on whether the type of the object is an array or not.

How about:

```
if (typeof(T).ImplementsInterface(typeof(IEnumerable)))
    someFunction<T>();
else
    someOtherFunction<T>();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray.aspx isn't good enough?

Comment: That would make more sense :D

Comment: No, I want to call the same function but with the arrayless type of the passed T type.